Opentelemetry Collector deplyed via Operator has duplicate metrics
I have this current setup:
Otel operator which deploys the Otel Collector as a K8s Deployment with 2 pods in my case.
In the same namespace I have a bunch of services configured with auto-instrumentation which push telemetry data to the otel collector service.
In the same namespace I have a PodMonitor which is used by Prometheus to discover the Otel Pods and scrape from them.
Both pods appear in Prometheus as targets , all seems to be good.
The problem that I am facing is that the metrics are duplicated. For the same service I have the same metric , each one comming from one otel-collector instance.
For example:
process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded{app_kubernetes_io_component="opentelemetry-collector", app_kubernetes_io_instance="platform.otel", app_kubernetes_io_managed_by="opentelemetry-operator", app_kubernetes_io_name="otel-collector", app_kubernetes_io_part_of="opentelemetry", app_kubernetes_io_version="latest", container="otc-container", container_id="a8616d3c490b842c66601c64b2bfead4e84de8277c408c69c7c4efd30539142d", endpoint="prometheus", exported_job="cwb-be", host_arch="amd64", host_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c-zlzkb", instance="10.43.151.208:8889", job="platform/otel-collector-pod-monitor", k8s_container_name="cwb-be", k8s_deployment_name="cwb-be", k8s_namespace_name="platform", k8s_node_name="aks-aerasvc1-95583755-vmss000000", k8s_pod_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c-zlzkb", k8s_replicaset_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c", namespace="platform", os_description="Linux 5.15.0-1051-azure", os_type="linux", pod="otel-collector-5dccb6749f-x6xkj", pod_template_hash="5dccb6749f", process_pid="9", process_runtime_description="Amazon.com Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.372-b07", process_runtime_name="OpenJDK Runtime Environment", process_runtime_version="1.8.0_372-b07", service_name="cwb-be", service_version="2.7.0-main-b153", telemetry_auto_version="1.32.1", telemetry_sdk_language="java", telemetry_sdk_name="opentelemetry", telemetry_sdk_version="1.34.1"}
25691

And the duplicate one , if you look closely you can see that the only difference is the collector that provided this metric
process_runtime_jvm_classes_loaded{app_kubernetes_io_component="opentelemetry-collector", app_kubernetes_io_instance="platform.otel", app_kubernetes_io_managed_by="opentelemetry-operator", app_kubernetes_io_name="otel-collector", app_kubernetes_io_part_of="opentelemetry", app_kubernetes_io_version="latest", container="otc-container", container_id="a8616d3c490b842c66601c64b2bfead4e84de8277c408c69c7c4efd30539142d", endpoint="prometheus", exported_job="cwb-be", host_arch="amd64", host_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c-zlzkb", instance="10.43.157.118:8889", job="platform/otel-collector-pod-monitor", k8s_container_name="cwb-be", k8s_deployment_name="cwb-be", k8s_namespace_name="platform", k8s_node_name="aks-aerasvc1-95583755-vmss000000", k8s_pod_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c-zlzkb", k8s_replicaset_name="cwb-be-685c64f54c", namespace="platform", os_description="Linux 5.15.0-1051-azure", os_type="linux", pod="otel-collector-5dccb6749f-7jhfg", pod_template_hash="5dccb6749f", process_pid="9", process_runtime_description="Amazon.com Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.372-b07", process_runtime_name="OpenJDK Runtime Environment", process_runtime_version="1.8.0_372-b07", service_name="cwb-be", service_version="2.7.0-main-b153", telemetry_auto_version="1.32.1", telemetry_sdk_language="java", telemetry_sdk_name="opentelemetry", telemetry_sdk_version="1.34.1"}
25691

In the first one the collector is: otel-collector-5dccb6749f-x6xkj and in the second one otel-collector-5dccb6749f-7jhfg. And the metric value is exactly the same. It seems like this metric is pushed to both collectors for some reson and then prometheus collects them both.
Am I doing something wrong with deploying 2 collector instances ? And is there a way to remove this duplication ?
What do you suggest I do ?
I don't understand how the service cand push the same metric to both collectors , because they are behind he lb provided via the K8s service.
PS: I can remove this at prometheus or grafana level , but I fear that I am doing something wrong.
Thanks

I believe the issue here is a limitation of Prometheus. Example:
If your metric hello is an otel updowncounter, this is translated into a prometheus gauge. If you have three pods sending hello{pod='<pod-name>'} 1 you would be sending the following to your pool of two collectors:
hello{pod='a'} 1
hello{pod='b'} 1
hello{pod='c'} 1

the sending from each of these pods to a collector is basically random unless you are using some custom load balancing strategy (which wouldn't be the case with auto-instrumentation).
hello{pod='a', collector='col-a'} 1
hello{pod='b', collector='col-a'} 1
hello{pod='c', collector='col-a'} 1
hello{pod='a', collector='col-b'} 1
hello{pod='b', collector='col-b'} 1
hello{pod='c', collector='col-b'} 1

So for each request, it could go to either collector. The issue reveals itself when aggregating in prometheus. If you are attempting to sum these metrics you will observe a factor of n for the actual value (where n is the amount of collectors in your pool.)
Here are your options to stop this from happening:

Use the prometheus remote write exporter to write the samples directly to prometheus
Send OTLP directly to prometheus (this is an alpha feature)
Aggregate these metrics using max to only get a single value


Thanks for the answer , and sorry for the late reply. What I don't get here is why is this happening ? because I have pod A pushing to the collector service with 2 instances , I expect to see the metric comming only from pod collector instance A OR instance B, not from both A and B. But every time , every metric is duplicated ... as if each of the collector instances holds a copy of that metric ... as if the collector pods have a shared storage ... but can't find any evidence of that unfortunately.
